# Use Heroku routing info in application

Tags: java, heroku

I am doing a web service in my Heroku app to check the status of the server and I would want to return some information that contains the router message, in logs is like this:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/checkServer" host=mywonderfulapp.herokuapp.com request_id=0123456-789-abc-def fwd="255.255.165.8" dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=290ms status=200 bytes=188
```

Is there any way to catch it using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the request id from the `"X-Request-ID"` header as described in the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id#usage-with-java). The dyno name is available from the `DYNO` environment variable.

What other values do you need? They are usually available somewhere, but you won't be able to wholesale lift the line that's logged by Heroku.

Comment: From this format of response I only needed the dyno name. Thanks

Comment: Cool. just for completeness then use `System.getenv("DYNO")`